# Can new users post images?

Tags: discussion

If you are a new user, are you allowed to post images (where they are visible in the body)?

Or, are people just lazy?

@Videonauth has probably done 100s of "made image viable" edits.

Comment: As far as I remember you have to have a certain amount of reputation for posting images :)

Comment: I think it's at 10 rep: http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user (@Videonauth).

Comment: Well if I come across a post where the image isn't visible I make it visible in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is "no, they can't."

Posting images and links are a privilege to help combat spam. See details here: https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user

Comment: They can however post links to the images which another user can then edit and convert to images. I've done this for new users a few times.