# How can I integrate pictures/images in review queues?

Tags: support, image

I can't figure out how I can integrate pictures when I read first posts in the review queue.

I hope I didn't oversee something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New users [aren't able to post images](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15666/606366) (to prevent spam or abusive material) and their posts often end up containing

- links to an image: [some text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99gX9.png)

  (source code: `[some text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99gX9.png)`)
- bare links to an image page like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSM58.jpg

The first case is easy to solve: just put a `!` in front of the opening square bracket: `![some text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99gX9.png)`. It's a little bit more work to make it clickable, probably the easiest way to do that is to use the image uploader (see below).

For the second case, I usually visit the website, right click on the image and choose something like 'Copy image location' (exact text depends on your browser):

[image]

You can either use that link to manually construct the necessary source code yourself (a la the previous example), or better: use the image uploader and use the 'paste an image or link' option:

[image]

Comment: Putting just a `!` in front would not make it clickable: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15566/480481

Comment: Yeah, that is sometimes useful. I've updated the answer to include that possibility.

Comment: *Most* of the time, from my personal experience. But the point is making it *non-clickable* would often cause an inconvenience to future readers, one would require to go through multiple extra steps (even harder in mobile devices) to get the link to the full-size image. On the other hand making it clickable would unlikely to cause any such inconvenience. So it's recommended to make it clickable always unless it's absolutely not required.

Comment: For the second case you mentioned, there may be copyright issues on images. It's most likely very rare, if ever. But it is something to keep in mind when copying images in order to host them on imgur.

Comment: True, I assumed this is (mostly) about questions by new users who are posting their screenshots. If I have to list every exception, this is going to be a very long answer ...